# Packaging Python file with cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze, easy-install

I am trying to package my Python code into an exe file but after following all the instructions on the link below, I managed to build the an exe file but when I try to run it, nothing happens.

```
       https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html
```

My setup.py file is

```
 import sys
  from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
  build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","tkinter", "pandas" , "openpyxl", "datetime", "time"]}  
  base = None
  if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"

   setup(  name = "login",
             version = "0.1",
             description = "My GUI application!",
              options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
              executables = [Executable("login.py", base=base)])
```

My login file runs without any error on Anaconda.

Can someone comment what may cause the problem?

Comment: How are you running the `.exe` and the original Python script?

Comment: By double clicking but i try to run it via console too and got no result....